# How to parse nested XML and extract attributes + tag text both?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

My XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<main_heading timestamp="20220113">
<details>
    <offer id="11" new_id="12">
        <level>1&amp;1</level>
        <typ>Green</typ>
        <name>Alpha</name>
        <visits>
            <name>DONT INCLUDE</name>
        </visits>
    </offer>
    <offer id="12" new_id="31">
        <level>1&amp;1</level>
        <typ>Yellow</typ>
        <name>Beta</name>
        <visits>
            <name>DONT INCLUDE</name>
        </visits>
    </offer>
</details>
</main_heading>
```

I want to parse certain fields into a dataframe.

Expected Output

```
timestamp   id     new_id   level      name
20220113    11     12       1&amp;1    Alpha
20220113    12     31       1&amp;1    Beta
```

where NAME nested within the "visits" tag is not included. I just want to consider the outer "name" tag.

```
timestamp = soup.find('main_heading').get('timestamp')
df[timestamp'] = timestamp
```

this solves one part

The rest I can do like this:

```
typ = []
for i in (soup.find_all('typ')):
    typ.append(i.text)
```

but i don't want to create several for loops for every new field

Comment: what exactly do you expect?

Comment: expected output is given in the qs above. A dataframe. @eike

Comment: expected output, yes, but not the constraints for the algorithm. you don't want to use for loops at all?

Comment: I am open to suggestions but i am hoping for something where i don't have to create a new long loop for each field (just in case i have too many fields to extract) if possible @eike

Comment: If you are only interested in single subfields of `offer`, would one loop over all `offer`s be acceptable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over the offers and select its previous `main_heading`:

```
for e in soup.select('offer'):
    data.append({
        'timestamp': e.find_previous('main_heading').get('timestamp'),
        'id':e.get('id'),
        'id_old':e.get('old_id'),
        'level':e.level.text,
        'typ':e.typ.text,
        'name':e.select_one('name').text
    })
```

Or in alternative to exclude only some elements and be more generic:

```
for e in soup.select('offer'):
    
    d = {
        'timestamp': e.find_previous('main_heading').get('timestamp'),
        'id':e.get('id'),
        'id_old':e.get('old_id'),
    }

    d.update({c.name:c.text for c in e.children if c.name is not None and 'visits' not in c.name})

    data.append(d)
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<main_heading timestamp="20220113">
<details>
    <offer id="11" new_id="12">
        <level>1&amp;1</level>
        <typ>Green</typ>
        <name>Alpha</name>
        <visits>
            <name>DONT INCLUDE</name>
        </visits>
    </offer>
    <offer id="12" new_id="31">
        <level>1&amp;1</level>
        <typ>Yellow</typ>
        <name>Beta</name>
        <visits>
            <name>DONT INCLUDE</name>
        </visits>
    </offer>
</details>
</main_heading>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml,'xml')

data = []

for e in soup.select('offer'):
    data.append({
        'timestamp': e.find_previous('main_heading').get('timestamp'),
        'id':e.get('id'),
        'id_old':e.get('old_id'),
        'level':e.level.text,
        'typ':e.typ.text,
        'name':e.select_one('name').text
    })

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

##### Output

|  | timestamp | id | id_old | level | typ | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 20220113 | 11 |  | 1&1 | Green | Alpha |
| 1 | 20220113 | 12 |  | 1&1 | Yellow | Beta |

Comment: Just out of interest, in this situation, is there a difference between `select("offer")` and `find_all("offer")`?

Comment: Not in this specific case, cause both use the elements name, but in general the fact that `select` uses `css selectors` -> https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors

Comment: @eike In addition, may check this q/a: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38028384/beautifulsoup-difference-between-find-and-select

Comment: @HedgeHog I think `xml.etree.ElementTree` is good enough here.

Answer (score 2):

pandas has [`.read_xml()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html)

You can use `xpath=` to pass custom XPath expressions to specify what to extract.

For example, `<offer>` and `<main_heading>` tags:

```
>>> pd.read_xml("main.xml", xpath="""//*[name() = "offer" or name() = "main_heading"]""")
    timestamp  details    id  new_id level     typ   name  visits
0  20220113.0      NaN   NaN     NaN  None    None   None     NaN
1         NaN      NaN  11.0    12.0   1&1   Green  Alpha     NaN
2         NaN      NaN  12.0    31.0   1&1  Yellow   Beta     NaN
```

From there you could `.ffill()` the timestamp and drop the details/visits columns:

```
>>> (pd.read_xml("main.xml", xpath="""//*[name() = "offer" or name() = "main_heading"]""")
...    .ffill()
...    .drop(columns=["details", "visits"])
...    .dropna()
... )
    timestamp    id  new_id level     typ   name
1  20220113.0  11.0    12.0   1&1   Green  Alpha
2  20220113.0  12.0    31.0   1&1  Yellow   Beta
```

Comment: Never thought of using the condition in the `xpath`, top alternative to work directly with `pandas`

Comment: Looks like we posted a few seconds apart - using the same idea! Great minds think alike (if I say so myself)!

Answer (score 1):

No need for any external library.

Core python is enough here.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<main_heading timestamp="20220113">
<details>
    <offer id="11" new_id="12">
        <level>1&amp;1</level>
        <typ>Green</typ>
        <name>Alpha</name>
        <visits>
            <name>DONT INCLUDE</name>
        </visits>
    </offer>
    <offer id="12" new_id="31">
        <level>1&amp;1</level>
        <typ>Yellow</typ>
        <name>Beta</name>
        <visits>
            <name>DONT INCLUDE</name>
        </visits>
    </offer>
</details>
</main_heading>'''

data = []
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
timestamp = root.attrib.get('timestamp')
for offer in root.findall('.//offer'):
    temp = {'timestamp': timestamp}
    for attr in ['id', 'new_id']:
        temp[attr] = offer.attrib.get(attr)
    for ele in ['level', 'name']:
        temp[ele] = offer.find(ele).text
    data.append(temp)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

output

```
  timestamp  id new_id level   name
0  20220113  11     12   1&1  Alpha
1  20220113  12     31   1&1   Beta
```

Comment: plausible alternative, will keep it in mind to keep it simpler if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness (and future visitors) here's another one: since we're dealing with xml and the final output is a dataframe - it's probably best (and simplest) to use [pandas.read_xml](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html):

```
df = pd.read_xml(xml,xpath='//offer')
ts = pd.read_xml(xml,xpath="//main_heading")['timestamp'][0]
df.insert(0, 'timestamp', ts)
print(df.drop(['typ', 'visits'], axis=1))
```

And that should get you your expected output.

Comment: Like the bouquet of possibilities, learned a few things again today - I find the direct use of `pandas` just as good as with @jqurious

Comment: @HedgeHog - "bouquet of possibilities" - you should definitely spend some of your SO time in a poetry site :).

Comment: Isn't there a little poet in all of us? We are source code poets, writing beautiful lettered soup, lookup for cute pandas, wondering about bouquet of possibilities. You're right, more poetry from today ;)